# Is this proof acceptable?

Tags: arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm, least-common-multiple

Proposition:

If $g$ is any common factor of $m$ and $n$ where $g,m,n \in$ $\mathbb N$
then $g \mid lcm(m,n)$

Proof:

As $m \mid lcm(m,n)$ and $n \mid lcm(m,n)$
by transitivity of divisibility $g \mid lcm(m,n)$ $$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Thanks!

Comment: It suffices to say that $g\,|\,m\; \&\;m\,|\,\text {lcm}(m,n)\implies g\,|\,\text {lcm}(m,n)$.  That is, you only need $g$ to divide one of the factors, not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably add that it follows from the definition of least common multiple that $m \mid \mathrm{lcm}(m,n)$.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance!